# How can I change the favicon when serving pdf documents on a Sitecore multisite installation

Tags: pdf, sitecore, favicon

I have multiple web sites running in a single Sitecore installation (iis site). Is there a way I can have different favicon.ico for each websites when serving pdf documents. Maybe by overriding Sitecore's MediaRequestHandler ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're currently just dropping in a `favicon.ico` file in the **wwwroot** for the site, that will show that icon for all sites on that instance. Since serving up media content goes through the `MediaRequestHandler` as you pointed out, that handler runs in the context on that IIS managed site, and therefore will show the root `favicon.ico`. The way to fix this for content pages is to reference a favicon via a meta tag in your specific layout, but I don't believe you can get around this for media items.

Comment: Thanx Mark! If found an alternative : embed the PDF document in a html page wich will use meta tags.